# Regex: Getting Variable from Substring

Tags: regex, search, numbers

How would I go about using Regex to extract the number from the following file:

```
abc_defg123_100aaa_abc_defg123
```

Where I want the `100` from the substring '`_100aaa_`'?

The closest have gotten is:

```
[0-9](?!(aaa_))*\w
```

but this matches up to the first underscore found!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<=_)\d+(?=aaa_)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/esbs79JKWcNSDL).

This regex uses look arounds to assert, without capturing, the delimiting input either side of the target.